# How do I run the canopy editor in blocking mode?

Tags: enthought, canopy

I would like to use the canopy editor as an external editor for a program. I need to be able to open the editor and block until the user saves and closes the editor. Right now, canopy returns immediately.

Is there a way to do that? Ideally it would be by running a python command that just opens the editor, and not the opening screen. Less ideal would be a way to test that the editor was still open.

Comment: Ah, I see you re-asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088253/how-to-test-if-canopy-editor-is-open . IMO you should only keep one of them alive since there is so much duplication between them. E.g. you could add the background from here to the question there if you like, or add the extra detail there to here...

Comment: They are semi-related. I would prefer a blocking solution because it is much easier to use. I need a solution on Mac/Win and Linux. The context of this is here: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/09/28/Editing-org-mode-python-source-blocks-in-an-external-editor-Canopy/